# Is it possible to have a html hyperlink to open tradingview to a specific symbol?

Tags: tradingview-api

Is it possible to create an external link to Tradingview.

My specific use case is to click an html hyperlink to open Tradingview  to a specific symbol ?

Comment: No idea what Tradingview is. Inspect the page source, and if any element there has an `id` or you see an `<a>` element with a `name`, you can use that in URL fragment (`http://example.com/...#theIDorNameThatYouSaw`) to make the browser scroll there (unless the element is dynamically generated).

Comment: good idea ! thanks

Answer (score 20):

> My specific use case is to click an html hyperlink to open Tradingview to a specific symbol ?

Yes, you can make hyperlinks for that of this format:

```
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=EXCHANGE:SYMBOL
```

If you are already logged in, that will show you the specified `SYMBOL` from the defined `EXCHANGE`.

For example:

- https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=AMEX:SPY to open a chart for the SPY tracker.
- https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BITFINEX:BTCUSD for BTC/USD prices from the Bitfinex exchange.
- https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ:AAPL for a chart with Apple's stock trading at the NASDAQ.

Comment: Are there other supported args such as date= or time= ?

Comment: To show same ticker on all charts within a window, enable symbol sync on all charts switch on the menu that appears when clicked on select layout button.
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000473336-how-do-i-change-the-ticker-symbol-for-all-charts-of-layout-simultaneously/

Answer (score 12):

You can also have custom resolution, i.e.:

```
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=FX:EURUSD&interval=120
```

([source](https://trading.codes/tutorials/stock-resolution-tradingview-chart-url-paremeters/))

Answer (score 1):

Answer above is solid, however I have found you can just skip the exchange if it is a popular ticker and I have never had an issue with a US based tickers. I launch a dozen or more tickers a day using the following method:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=SYMBOL

Examples such as:

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=AAPL

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BTCUSD

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=US500

One thing to note is that it will not always work if you launch multiple in quick succession. I currently launch with a delay of 0.8 seconds between each.